# How to import table from csv file using a relative path in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

My COPY function is this: `COPY NEWTABLE FROM './myfile.csv' csv HEADER;`

But when I try such a thing, it tells me `No such file or directory`. Only when I use absolute path does it work, but for the purposes of what I'm doing I need to use some sort of relative path.

Answer (score 2):

In linux, with psql I do:

```
\set localpath `pwd`'/myfile.csv'
COPY NEWTABLE FROM :'localpath' csv HEADER;
```

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` runs on the server backend, which means it's pwd is usually your cluster's `datadir` - any relative paths it tries to look up will be relative to there. See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.52.8):

> The path will be interpreted relative to the working directory of the server process (normally the cluster's data directory), not the client's working directory.

If you're using psql, `\copy` will Do The Right Thing with relative paths (it'll use your pwd, not the server backend's)